# how to make hyperlink to other viewcontroller based on calculating result?

Tags: ios, hyperlink

i'm make a diet application which is can tell user how much calories do they need per day by input the data like height, weight and age. then the result will be appear when user press "hitung" button. After that user will press next button bellow or i called "selanjutnya" then user will find the food menu who can they choose based on their calorie per day such as >1400, >1600, >1800, >2000 then when user press one of those choices the food menu will be appear. but i have difficulty to make it simple, i want is when the result appear user can click on calorie result and directly go to food menu without choose in next page.

exp: when the result is 1823, user can press the result and directly go to food menu that serve >1800 calories.

Answer (score 0):

```
//In the button action method
if(calories > 2000)
{
    // show food items type 1
}
else if (calories > 1800)
{
    // show food items type 2
}
else if (calories > 1600)
{
    // show food items type 3
}
... // so on
else
{
    // show food items type n
}
```

Comment: how to add food items? the result is a label?

Comment: You must provide details of your app including the code and screenshots in your questions, not by sending emails to users.